# FFMPEG amerge fails when one audio stream is missing

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to combine two video files (of size 320x240) and create a single, horizontally extended output video file (of size 640x240) but for the audio merging, the command fails when one of the input files does not contain audio stream.

Here's the command I am using:

**C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "input1.flv" -i "input2.flv" -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x240[base];[0:v]scale=320x240[upperleft];[1:v]scale=320x240[upperright];[base][upperleft]overlay=shortest=1[tmp1];[tmp1][upperright]overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=0;[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map [aout] -ac 2 "output.mp4"**

This command works fine when both input1.flv and input2.flv contain audio tracks. When either one lacks an audio track, the command gives the following error:

> [flv @ 0000000004300660] Stream discovered after head already parsed
>   [flv @ 0000000004300660] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1
>   (Audio: none, 0 channels): unspecified sample format Consider
>   increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
>   Input #1, flv, from 'input2.flv':   Metadata:
>       creationdate    : Tue Jan 26 16:50:12   Duration: 00:25:59.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 212 kb/s
>       Stream #1:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 320x240, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
>       Stream #1:1: Audio: none, 0 channels
>       Stream #1:2: Data: none [abuffer @ 0000000004335620] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+009] [abuffer @
>   0000000004335620] Unable to parse option value "(null)" as sample
>   format [abuffer @ 0000000004335620] Value inf for parameter
>   'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+009] [abuffer @
>   0000000004335620] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0. [graph
>   0 input from stream 1:1 @ 00000000042e4d60] Error applying options to
>   the filter. Error configuring filters.

Is there a way to make this command work even when one audio stream lacks an audio track or both of the audio streams lack audio tracks?

Comment: When do they contain audio - are they mono, stereo?

Comment: @Mulvya All audio streams of our input files are mono.

Comment: Does it have to work with one command or can you use different commands with different situations?

Comment: @Mulvya Well it would be nice to be able to use a single command because I'm calling this from a C# code and it is hard to use different commands with different situations.However, if it is impossible, different commands with different situations would be OK as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's one preparatory command that needs to be executed only once,to generate a file

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc:r=48000 silence.mkv
```

---

For each flv,

```
ffmpeg -i input1.flv -analyzeduration 10M -i silence.mkv -c copy -map 0 -map 1 input1a.mkv

ffmpeg -i input2.flv -analyzeduration 10M -i silence.mkv -c copy -map 0 -map 1 input2a.mkv
```

And then,

```
ffmpeg -i input1a.mkv -i input2a.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack=shortest=1[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -ac 2 "output.mp4"
```

Comment: When I execute the first command I get the following error: [lavfi @ 000000000428e540] No such filter: 'anullsrc:d'
anullsrc:d=1: Invalid argument

Comment: Try now, With time set via option.

Comment: The first command worked this time and I was able to generate silence.mp4 but this time I get the following error when issuing the second command: [mp4 @ 00000000042dba80] Could not find tag for codec flv1 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
...
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Error number -22 occurred

Comment: Try outputting to mkv

Comment: I get "sample rate not set" error when I try outputting to mkv: Input #0, flv, from 'input2.flv':
  ...
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'silence.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.22.103
  Duration: 00:00:01.04, start: 0.036281, bitrate: 136 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[matroska @ 000000000432a9a0] sample rate not set