# Trying to convert a VideoCD MPEG to MP4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a VideoCD MPEG to MP4 using:

FFMPEG 5.1

```
ffmpeg.exe -nostdin -y -loglevel info -hide_banner -i "ITEM0010.DAT" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -qscale:v 3  -c:a aac -ar 96000 -map_metadata -1 "output.mp4"
```

I'm getting:

```
[mpeg @ 0000024b81bf4480] start time for stream 1 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpeg @ 0000024b81bf4480] stream 1 : no TS found at start of file, duration not set
[mpeg @ 0000024b81bf4480] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mpeg, from 'C:\Concierge\ITEM0010.DAT':
  Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16p
  Stream #0:2[0x1e2]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 704x576 [SAR 178:163 DAR 1958:1467], 1100 kb/s, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (mpeg1video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] -qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended.
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] using SAR=178/163
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[abuffer @ 0000024b84979880] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+09]
    Last message repeated 1 times
[abuffer @ 0000024b84979880] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0.
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000024b85187c00] Error applying options to the filter.
Error reinitializing filters!
Error while filtering: Result too large
Finishing stream 0:1 without any data written to it.
[abuffer @ 0000024b84979880] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+09]
    Last message repeated 1 times
[abuffer @ 0000024b84979880] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0.
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000024b85186b00] Error applying options to the filter.
Error configuring filter graph
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] frame I:1     Avg QP:22.68  size: 40674
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] mb I  I16..4:  3.8% 72.3% 23.9%
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] 8x8 transform intra:72.3%
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 88.4% 81.1% 50.3%
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] i16 v,h,dc,p: 43% 13%  0% 43%
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 16% 20%  5%  5%  6%  5%  7%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 20%  8%  5%  9%  8%  8%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000024b81c86000] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 23% 28%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000024b
```

81c86000] kb/s:8134.80
Conversion failed!

The same command using FFMPEG 4.1 works fine.

Comment: Can you share a sample DAT file? What is the result of `ffmpeg.exe -y -loglevel info -hide_banner -i ITEM0010.DAT -c copy output.mp4`? Try adding `-f mpeg` to the input `ffmpeg.exe -f mpeg -y ...`. Try increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an empty (maybe, really empty) audio track placed first before the video track in the interleave options (possibly corrupted MPEG2 mux with number of channels set explicitly to 0):

```
[mpeg @ 0000024b81bf4480] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mpeg, from 'C:\Concierge\ITEM0010.DAT':
  Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16p
```

At first, try to use `ffprobe` or `mediainfo` to determine the exact format of an audio track, then try to tune `analyzeduration` parameter to let the header be read properly. If the video does not contain audio at all (usually for the slideshows made in applications such as Roxio Video Creator), you may try to fake the audio track with pre-generated silent audio like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206525/9560245) or to exclude it with `-an`.